# PDO get restults from about 1.000.000 records

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, execution

I have an script that I need to select an top 10 from about 500.000 - 1.000.000 records
I use MSSQL Server 2008

My website  is steed up to use the PDO class but when I try to get top 10 from records my database and webserver gets hanged up and give me execution time exceed error.

If I use mssql class, everyting is fine and works ok, but if I use pdo my website get stucked.

Any ideeas how to make my script work and echo the top 10 I need?

This is my pdo script

```
$char = $db->prepare("SELECT TOP 10 Name FROM Character ORDER BY PvPLastStandWin DESC");
    $char->execute();

    foreach($char as $row){
        echo $row[0].'<br>';

    }
```

Comment: Have a look the the PDO::query() method.

Comment: Try adding `LIMIT 10` after `DESC`

Comment: @Fred-ii- MS SQL doesn't use that syntax.

Comment: Thanks @GordonM - I thought they used a similar convention. (noted)